# Office 365 Groups expiration policy

Tags: sharepoint-online, provisioning

It was discovered that one of our highly active SharePoint sites was deleted this morning. After digging through the logs, I found "Site Deleted" by "AAD SharePoint Sync".

After looking into this it seems like there is an expiration on Groups? Can someone explain at a high-level? Are there considerations we should have when provisioning sites with O365 Groups  so they aren't deleted?

Answer (score 1):

Office 365 Group expiration is part of Azure AD and requires at least P1 licenses for all users contained in the Group. An Azure administrator sets the timeframe for expiration. There is an additional feature that can be enabled which expires based on lack of activity, such as visiting the SharePoint site. There is also a catch-all email address you can configure if the Group has no active Owner(s).

As features and functionality change over time, I'll post a link to the [Office 365 Group Expiration Policy](https://docs.microsoft.com/office365/admin/create-groups/office-365-groups-expiration-policy?view=o365-worldwide) documentation.

Comment: Good info! The expiration is off by default. Azure portal is showing no expiration on the site in question. The site was active and so was the Owner. The Audit shows no reasoning either so we're just struggling to find our lesson learned